# How to get an entry point address in binary image file generated by objcopy?

Tags: rust, embedded, riscv, objcopy

I am building an emulator of the Risk-V CPU for own educational purposes. I have small POC working and want to build example programs and test them on the emulator.

I'm trying to build example program in Rust and seems like I made some decent progress, but I got stuck when I have to load compiled program to the memory of my emulator and transfer CPU execution to that program.

Test program:

```rust
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use core::panic::PanicInfo;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn _start() -> ! {
    loop {
        for i in 0..1000 {
            unsafe {
                let r = i as *mut u32;
                // This can panic because (500 - i) can be 0
                *r = 20000 % (500 - i);
            }
        }
    }
}

#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
    loop {}
}
```

build:

```sh
$ cargo build --target riscv32i-unknown-none-elf --release
```

generating binary image from elf target:

```sh
riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-objcopy -g -O binary \
  target/riscv32i-unknown-none-elf/release/sample1 \
  target/riscv32i-unknown-none-elf/release/sample1.bin
```

This works fine so far and generates me binary file with size 5156 bytes.

I inspected .bin file and it looks "legit binary" to me.
I found some readable strings in the beginning of the file (like `attempt to calculate the remainder with a divisor of zero`) - looks like they are related to code which handles panic which can happen if I'm doing `% 0`.
In the end of file I found something that looks like riskv32i instructions (easy to notice them since least significant bits are `11`).
Rest of the file is filled with zeros.

Place where I stuck is I cannot figure out:

1. At which offset am I supposed to load this bin image file into memory of my virtual CPU? I don't think it's OK to load it at 0x0 address, because there is useful info in the beginning of the image and I don't think it's cool for the program to read it from address 0x0.
2. After program is loaded, I need to transfer CPU execution to the entry point of my program (`_start`). How can I find out which address is the entry point so I can put this address into `pc` register before starting CPU cycles? It's obviously not in the beginning of the image (there are human readable strings there).
3. Is there a way to make this entry point address stable, so all programs which I write will have the same entry point address, so I don't have to do tweaks for each of programs I compile?

I may went wrong way when I used `objcopy`. If that's the case, please let me know what's the appropriate way to load ELF file into a homemade CPU emulator.

Update: Linker arguments, (as provided by `RUSTFLAGS="-Z print-link-args" cargo build --target riscv32i-unknown-none-elf --release --verbose`):

```sh
rust-lld \
    -flavor \
    gnu \
    -L \
    /home/kris/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv32i-unknown-none-elf/lib \
    /mnt/c/src/ws/cpu/sample1/target/riscv32i-unknown-none-elf/release/deps/sample1-4813691a581d1819.sample1.251h7tq6-cgu.0.rcgu.o \
    /mnt/c/src/ws/cpu/sample1/target/riscv32i-unknown-none-elf/release/deps/sample1-4813691a581d1819.sample1.251h7tq6-cgu.1.rcgu.o -o \
    /mnt/c/src/ws/cpu/sample1/target/riscv32i-unknown-none-elf/release/deps/sample1-4813691a581d1819 \
    --gc-sections \
    -L \
    /mnt/c/src/ws/cpu/sample1/target/riscv32i-unknown-none-elf/release/deps \
    -L \
    /mnt/c/src/ws/cpu/sample1/target/release/deps \
    -L \
    /home/kris/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv32i-unknown-none-elf/lib \
    -Bstatic \
    /home/kris/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv32i-unknown-none-elf/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-6d1cf467df9db3bb.rlib \
    /home/kris/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv32i-unknown-none-elf/lib/libcore-a1a0b4993598bfe4.rlib \
    /home/kris/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/riscv32i-unknown-none-elf/lib/libcompiler_builtins-a229bbbccd019775.rlib \
    -Bdynamic
```

*I know that there are some important things missing in the program, like initializing stack pointer register. I'm planning to take care about that after I figure out loading logic*

Comment: About (3), I don't think so, since in the beginning there is a static memory, which contains all the static data used by your program (as you mentioned - string literals, as well as some extras)

Comment: Could you please augment your question with the exact content of your linker script ?

Comment: Just some ideas: I would try to use `objdump` to get the information from the ELF file. Pure binary files don't have any meta data. -- If you have the linker script, you might try to copy and edit it to get a fixed entry address. -- For deeper inspection you could compare the disassembly of both the ELF and the binary files.

Comment: Frant, I added linker arguments tot he question, I hope that's what you asking for. It's auto-generated by the rustc compiler.

Comment: the busybee, I did some experiments with `objdump -d` and `objdump -f`. It tells me `start address 0x000111d8` and that matches with objdump disassembly `_start` function location. The problem is this address would be outside of my binary image produced by `objcopy` (which is just ~5kb).
`objcopy` documentation says "The memory dump will start at the load address of the lowest section copied into the output file." - how can I figure out what's the address of the "lowest section copied into the output file"? I think that would tell me at which offset to load my binary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not familiar with Rust, but your question is more related to the ELF file format and tools that can understand it - my two cents.

1. Which offset you should load your binary file at should probably be guided by the linker settings rust-ldd is using.

For example, this [documentation](https://docs.rs/riscv-rt/0.8.0/riscv_rt/) describes a file memory.x defining the memory map used by the linker:

```
MEMORY
{
  RAM : ORIGIN = 0x80000000, LENGTH = 16K
  FLASH : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 16M
}

REGION_ALIAS("REGION_TEXT", FLASH);
REGION_ALIAS("REGION_RODATA", FLASH);
REGION_ALIAS("REGION_DATA", RAM);
REGION_ALIAS("REGION_BSS", RAM);
REGION_ALIAS("REGION_HEAP", RAM);
REGION_ALIAS("REGION_STACK", RAM);
```

In this example, the resulting binary should probably be loaded at offset `0x20000000`.

There should be an equivalent with the toolchain you are using.

2. You can find `_start` using a tool that understands the ELF file format.

For example, `aarch64-none-elf-nm` on one of my executables compiled for Aarch64 will display:

```
aarch64-none-elf-nm h5-example.elf
0000000042000078 t $d
0000000042000000 t $x
0000000042000080 t $x
00000000420001dc t $x
00000000420001f4 t $x
0000000042000230 B __bss_end__
0000000042000230 B __bss_start__
0000000042000080 T c_entry
000000004200022c D __copy_table_end__
0000000042000220 D __copy_table_start__
0000000042000230 D __data_end__
0000000042000230 D __data_start__
0000000042000230 ? __end__
0000000042000230 B __etext
0000000042000218 T __exidx_end
0000000042000218 T __exidx_start
0000000042000230 d __fini_array_end
0000000042000230 d __fini_array_start
0000000046000230 ? __HeapLimit
0000000004000000 A __HEAP_SIZE
0000000042000230 d __init_array_end
0000000042000230 d __init_array_start
00000000420001f4 T main
0000000042000000 A __RAM_BASE
000000000e000000 A __RAM_SIZE
0000000042000000 T Reset_Handler
0000000000000000 A __ROM_BASE
0000000000000000 A __ROM_SIZE
000000004c000000 ? __StackLimit
0000000004000000 A __STACK_SIZE
0000000050000000 ? __StackTop
00000000420001dc t system_read_CurrentEL
0000000042000230 B __zero_table_end__
0000000042000230 B __zero_table_start__
```

In my case, the first instruction be be executed would be at `Reset_Handler`.
I could retrieve the line referencing it using the following command:

```
aarch64-none-elf-nm h5-example-02.elf | grep ' Reset_Handler$'
0000000042000000 T Reset_Handler
```

and its exact address in hexadecimal using:

```
aarch64-none-elf-nm h5-example-02.elf | grep ' Reset_Handler$' | cut -d ' ' -f1
0000000042000000

RESET_HANDLER=$(aarch64-none-elf-nm h5-example-02.elf | grep ' Reset_Handler$' | cut -d ' ' -f1)
echo ${RESET_HANDLER}
```

would of course display:

```
0000000042000000
```

Now the start address is known, there would be several options for using it in your DIY emulator. The two that came to my mind would be:

a) pass the address as an argument to your emulator, i.e.:

`my-emulator 0000000042000000` or `my-emulator -s 0000000042000000`

b) since you master the format of the image your emulator will load, you could convene to systematically prepend the start address to the binary file produced by objcopy: this way, you would read the first 4 or 8 bytes of the binary file first, getting your start address, then read the remaining bytes.

An easy way to do so would for example  to use `xxd` and `cat`:

```
echo 0000000042000000 | xxd -r -p > final-image.bin
cat sample1.bin >> final-image.bin
```

Using an example file containing 'ABCD', we would get:

```
printf "ABCD" > sample1.bin
hexdump -C sample1.bin
00000000  41 42 43 44                                       |ABCD|
00000004

echo 0000000042000000 | xxd -r -p > final-image.bin
hexdump -C final-image.bin

00000000  00 00 00 00 42 00 00 00                           |....B...|
00000008

cat sample1.bin >> final-image.bin
hexdump -C final-image.bin
00000000  00 00 00 00 42 00 00 00  41 42 43 44              |....B...ABCD|
0000000c
```

You could of course define a more complicated header, may be containing some other important symbols, or add more command-line options to you emulator - the basic principle would remain the same.

3. Yes, you could probably force your compiler to put the `_start()` function into a specific linker section, as described [here](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/embedonomicon/memory-layout.html), using the `link_section` directive/pragma:

Program:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn Reset() -> ! {
    let _x = 42;

    // can't return so we go into an infinite loop here
    loop {}
}

// The reset vector, a pointer into the reset handler
#[link_section = ".vector_table.reset_vector"]
#[no_mangle]
pub static RESET_VECTOR: unsafe extern "C" fn() -> ! = Reset;
```

Linker script:

```
/* Memory layout of the LM3S6965 microcontroller */
/* 1K = 1 KiBi = 1024 bytes */
MEMORY
{
  FLASH : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 256K
  RAM : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 64K
}

/* The entry point is the reset handler */
ENTRY(Reset);

EXTERN(RESET_VECTOR);

SECTIONS
{
  .vector_table ORIGIN(FLASH) :
  {
    /* First entry: initial Stack Pointer value */
    LONG(ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM));

    /* Second entry: reset vector */
    KEEP(*(.vector_table.reset_vector));
  } > FLASH

  .text :
  {
    *(.text .text.*);
  } > FLASH

  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    *(.ARM.exidx .ARM.exidx.*);
  }
}
```

This way, the code for the `_start()` function would always be put at the beginning of the `.vector_table` section, which is defined a being the first in the FLASH region.

The address for `_start()` would therefore always be `0x00000000`, or whatever address you will decide the reset address will be in your CPU: you would just have to modify the address where the FLASH region is starting from.

The example is related to an Arm Cortex-M MCU, and you could replace the `.vector_table` section by, say, your own `.startup` section.

I hope I was not off-track on that one...

Comment: Frant, I want to thank you for the great and detailed explanation. I followed the first half and was able to produce a binary which seems like has entry point in the beginning of the .bin file and I'm assuming if I load it with offset you suggested it would give me right entry point as well! It seems like `riscv_rt` crate which you linked does necessary magic to align things in the ELF file and then I can use your scripts to extract offset using `nm`. I don't completely understand what `riscv_rt` is doing to accomplish that and will have to learn it more :)

Comment: You are welcome. Forgot to mention that the start address prepended to your binary would have to be converted to little endian in the case your emulator would run on a  little endian system, which should be the case. Using a function like [bswap_64()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bswap.3.html)  or [bswap_32()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bswap.3.html)  would do.